# how to replace the value of a column with factor level based on defined factors in R

Tags: r

I have a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwtr4KKIbBfkQ0tkQS1vaElSNkU), where I defined the factors for rows `gene.fac` and columns `cell.fac`.

```
load('Analysis.RData')
top200_groups <- data.frame (cluster = cell.fac,  t(top200))
melted <- melt(top200_groups, id.vars=c("cluster"))
```

After the application with `melt` function, I can see

[image]

Then I want to replace the genename in `melted$variable` with the factors defined in `gene.fac`.

Is there easy way to transform this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
load('Analysis.RData')
top200_groups <- data.frame (cluster = cell.fac,  t(top200))
melted <- melt(top200_groups, id.vars=c("cluster"))

df2 <- as.data.frame(gene.fac)
df2$variable <- factor(rownames(df2))

df_new <- full_join(melted, df2, by = "variable")
```

The new `data.frame` `df_new` has two columns, your old one and the new one. You can erase the old one. 
There is also warning but no error, when you execute the code, that `dplyr` changed to character.